# button click event is not change

Tags: c#, asp.net

i need some help what is wrong in this code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ }

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Button1.ID = "Button4";
   Button2.ID = "Button1";
   Button1.Click -= Button1_Click;
   Button1.Click +=new EventHandler( Button2_Click);
   //Button2.ID = "Button1";
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("success"); 
}
```

When i click on button1, it calls button1_click and when i click on button2, it also calls button1_click instead of button2_click.

Comment: i need to assign button1 id to button2 and button2 click event call as it is call button2_Click but code is not working

Answer (score 0):

I believe this could be your problem:

```
Button2.ID = "Button1";
```

According to the [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.id(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) setting `Control.ID` will *"provide you with programmatic access to the server control's properties, **events**, and methods."*. You literally seem to assign `Button1` to `Button2`, making `Button2` fire the event subscribed by `Button1`.

Remove the `Button2.ID` line and I think it should work.

If it still doesn't work I recommend you to look through the .Designer.cs file and see if you've subscribed to the `Button2_Click` event.